# Why is setting color of a html entity character failing?

Tags: css

I have this character code `<span class="psi">&#936;</span>` for a `psi` greek character.

This is the css code for

```
.psi{
color:red !important;
}
```

the class `psi`.When i try the code out in my firefox web browser,the character is not red. Why is this?.

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/8svwe5up/

Comment: Ditto - http://jsfiddle.net/jgkv9b9q/1/ in FF35 & Chrome

Comment: What version of Firefox do you have? I believe the latest is 35.0. On another note, does it have the same effect in other web browsers (Chrome, Safari, IE)?

Comment: The class was being overridden by another.Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can happen only if you have another rule (*more specific*) with `!important` that also applies to that element.

For example

```css
#wrapper span{
    color:blue !important;
}
.psi {
    color:red !important;
    font-size:3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <span class="psi">&#936;</span>
</div>
```

So check for overlapping rules.
(*and try to not use `!important`. You should be able to do what you want by using more specific css rules*)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the color of some html entities in Firefox (at least up to 60.0b8). Some examples are ❓ and :

```css
.psi{
  color:blue !important;
}
```

```html
<span class="psi">&#10067;</span>
```

It works in Chrome.